# Chrome (Electron) list styling

Tags: css, google-chrome, html-lists

I have a list that I'm trying to imitate where the items are numbered poorly. This is a nested list, with the inner counters using lowercase alpha. But the outer counter appears prefixed to each of the inner counters, something like...

```
1) List item blah
2a) Yet another list item
2b) And another again
```

Such that visually the inner lists aren't nested/indented at all.

I am not committed to how the markup looks, if this could be done as a single html ol somehow, I'd be ok with that, but I'll also go through and do it as a proper nested list if I must for this effect.

I was excited when I stumbled across Mozilla MDN's "@counter-style" functionality, but it appears that isn't supported in Chrome (let alone whichever version is part of my Electron app).

Is there an efficient way to do this with html/css?

I'm linking some example markup/css for this which doesn't work. Note that it includes the extraneous "2)" marker that I can't figure out how to hide.

https://jsfiddle.net/au8pvrex/